# pause or stop Firefox 'tamper data'?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have been using 'tamper data' of Firefox to sniff the requests sent back and forth. I don't change the requests, just want a clear view of them. 'tamper data' is a great tool, except for 1 thing, to me,

there is no way to pause, ie, stop tracking requests. I have an application that is sending an ajax call every 1 second or so. All I want is to track the initial requests when the applciation starts. but the ajax calls keep polluting the 'tamper data' window and I cannot get hold of the initial requests as they get rolled to the top.

Can anyone please share some hints to achieve what I want? Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

the net tab of firebug does not have that problem. It always fixes on the earliest entries